# Running Spyder code on GPU instead of CPU on Ubuntu

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu, nvidia

I am working on Spyder to create deep learning model on a machine have a GPU I have found that am working on a CPU and my code run for a long time.First I downloaded tensorflow-GPU but I don't how to start working on GPU .

I used { `with tf.device("cpu"):` } but when I write nvidia-smi on terminal I found no running processes.

I also used { `import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"

os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = ""` } but it doesn't work.

How to make my Spyder code run on GPU instead of cpu on Ubuntu?

Any help would be appreciated.

**code:**

```
def createModel():
   with tf.device("cpu"):
        input_shape=(1, 22, 5, 3844)
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Conv3D(16, (22, 5, 5), strides=(1, 2, 2), padding='same',activation='relu',data_format= "channels_first", input_shape=input_shape))

        model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1, 2, 2),data_format= "channels_first",  padding='same'))

        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Conv3D(32, (1, 3, 3), strides=(1, 1,1), padding='same',data_format= "channels_first",  activation='relu'))#incertezza se togliere padding

        model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1,2, 2),data_format= "channels_first", ))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Conv3D(64, (1,3, 3), strides=(1, 1,1), padding='same',data_format= "channels_first",  activation='relu'))#incertezza se togliere padding
        model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1,2, 2),data_format= "channels_first",padding='same' ))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=64,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001), activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.0001)))
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))
        model.add(Dense(256, activation='sigmoid'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))
        model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
        opt_adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt_adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

Comment: Can you specify which video card you are using. Maybe your problem is just about technical. Also make sure that you install gpu version of tensorflow.

Comment: @AbdullahDeliogullari I write nvidia-smi in terminal I got this output  NVIDIA-SMI 440.82       Driver Version: 440.82       CUDA Version: 10.2

Comment: Ok, that means its not a technical problem. Probably 2 different tensorflow versions casued this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [github discussion](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12388) there are 2 ways to solve that problem:

1. Uninstall tensorflow and install downgrade version of tensorflow

   ```
   pip uninstall tensorflow
   pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu
   pip install tensorflow==1.8.0
   pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.8.0
   ```
2. If you have more than 1 GPU

   ```
   export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='0'
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me . I will try uninstall and install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0. I hope this will work.

Comment: I think you should downgrade your tensorflow to 1.8.0. Version 2.0.0 still can be problematic. After your try, let me know whether this solution worked or not.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.Thanks a lot for the solution. It works  with me.

Comment: Can I work on the CPU of the server while installing tensorflow-gpu 1.15.8 ?? I want to compare the speed of my code.

Comment: If you install cpu and gpu version of tensorflow seperately as in my answer,  you can use both of them with changing tf.device to cpu

Comment: I use with tf.device('/cpu:0'): but it didn't work. Any other suggestion , please.

Comment: I use this 
`os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"  
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = ""`

but I use those two lines with tensorflow-gpu and it works on CPU I don't if that true .

Comment: Abdullah Deliogullari Thanks a lot for your help.I really appreciate it.It works.

Comment: Glad to hear that